# Jython import Python methods AND variables in java (Load the whole script basically)

Tags: java, python, scope, jython

I found a way to import a Python Script into java and call one of its methods with Jython thanks to stackoverflow:

```
interface DataRetriever {public Object retrieveData();}

...

PythonInterpreter interpreter;
PyObject fun;
DataRetriever dr;

...

interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
Py.getSystemState().path.append(new PyString("Scripts/"));

interpreter.exec("from " + pythonFileName + "import *");
fun = interpreter.get("retrieveData");
dr = (DataRetriever) fun.__tojava__(DataRetriever.class);

...

public Object thisIsGettingCalledPrettyOften(){
    return dr.retrieveData();
}
```

Now, if my method in the python script only uses local variables, for example:

```
def retrieveData():
    a = 2
    b = 4
    c = a + b
    return c
```

, everything works fine.

Unfortunately, I absolutely need to have some variables defined globally so that they their value persists between multiple calls to retrieveData - But the "from script import *" apparently does not import those variables. Example script:

```
timesCalled = 0
def retrieveData():
    timesCalled += 1
    return timesCalled
```

How do I also import those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a "global" statement in my retrieveData function. Simple python error apparently...